# Eventbus onMessageEvent not getting called

Tags: android, callback, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I have implemented EventBus in my project but I am not getting all of my events

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent2());
            }
        });
    }
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "MainActivity called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    };

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

Here i created 2 event inside onClick(); 
And this is my AnotherActivity where i have another @Subscribe

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);
    }

    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent2 event2)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "AnotherActivity called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Not getting called
    };

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

I dont know why my second toast is not getting called, i have done every thing correctly.

What i suspect is the `AnotherActivity` is not created yet so my event is not called is that is so what is use of EventBus then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What i suspect is the AnotherActivity is not created yet so my event
>   is not called is that is so

Yes, if the event happened in past and the component(activity) is not active/created then the event will not be received.

> what is use of EventBus then?

You can use [Sticky Event](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) to listen to past events in newly created activity

so use `postSticky`

```
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEvent2());
```

and add `sticky = true` in `subscribe` annotation

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent2 event2){
    Toast.makeText(this, "AnotherActivity called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//Not getting called
};
```

or you can receive them manually

```
MessageEvent2 msg2 = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(MessageEvent2.class);
// you can also remove it using
// EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(msg2);
```

or remove it from history as well

```
MessageEvent2 msg2 = EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(MessageEvent2.class);
if(msg2!=null){//do something}
```

Comment: im getting Exception as
> Caused by: org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBusException: Subscriber class akki.amoledlauncher.rv.Main2Activity already registered to event class akki.amoledlauncher.ListenerEvent 

when im using in my actual project

Comment: when you are getting exception? explain it plz

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot, i was missing to unregister eventBus onStop so it was trying to subscribe again when activity was created

Comment: I am glad that I could help, happy coding